# Way of recalculating keys after using array_unique in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I remove dupliactes from array (list #1) with `array_uniqe` but how to recalculate kyes of it's output (list #2) to [0-x] (list #3):

**list #1:**

```
 array (size=24)
          0 => string '2013-09-18' (length=10)
          1 => string '2013-09-18' (length=10)
          2 => string '2013-09-18' (length=10)
          3 => string '2013-09-18' (length=10)
          4 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
          5 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
          6 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
          7 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
          8 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
          9 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
          10 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
          11 => string '2013-09-20' (length=10)
          12 => string '2013-09-20' (length=10)
          13 => string '2013-09-20' (length=10)
          14 => string '2013-09-20' (length=10)
          15 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
          16 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
          17 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
          18 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
          19 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
          20 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
          21 => string '2013-09-22' (length=10)
          22 => string '2013-09-22' (length=10)
          23 => string '2013-09-22' (length=10)
```

**List #2:**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '2013-09-18' (length=10)
  4 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
  11 => string '2013-09-20' (length=10)
  15 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
  21 => string '2013-09-22' (length=10)
```

**List #3:**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '2013-09-18' (length=10)
  1 => string '2013-09-19' (length=10)
  2 => string '2013-09-20' (length=10)
  3 => string '2013-09-21' (length=10)
  4 => string '2013-09-22' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$list3 = array_values($list2);
```